# Simple fix for formerly damp patch on the wall

Tags: walls, plaster

The pipe above this vent was dripping against the wall, the drops has been fixed and the wall has dried out. But the plaster/wall around it is an odd combination of powery and spongy, and feel like some special form of plaster was used, and the vent to the outside is coming away slightly.

Is there any simple, relatively neat solution to fixing this? Such as expanding foam. Probably needs to be semi weather-resistant as cold and wind come through the vent a lot.

[image]

Comment: Heath Robinson called & wants his plumbing back;) [sorry, couldn't resist.]

Comment: About the only simple fix is remove and replace with something.  The plaster is ruined/can't be fixed.  Remove all damage plaster.  Can replace with almost any wall covering(drywall).

Comment: Had to look him up, @Tetsujin. #TIL. Thanks! (continuing the cross-pond education!)

Comment: Heath Robinson:Rube Goldberg::Tomahto:Tomayto

Answer (score 3):

Remove back to sound plaster.

Clean throughly.

Apply new plaster.

Comment: It ain't rocket surgery!